# How do I convert unicode string with cp1252 characters into UTF-8 with Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I am getting text through an API that returns characters with a windows encoded apostrophe (\x92):

```
> python
>>> title = u'There\x92s thirty days in June'
>>> title
u'There\x92s thirty days in June'
>>> print title
Theres thirty days in June
>>> type(title)
<type 'unicode'>
```

I'm trying to convert this string to UTF-8 so that it instead returns: "There’s thirty days in June"

When I try to decode or encode this unicode string, it throws an error:

```
>>> title.decode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x92' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> title.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x92' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

If I were to initialize the string as plain-text and then decode it, it works:

```
>>>title = 'There\x92s thirty days in June'
>>> type(title)
<type 'str'>
>>>print title.decode('cp1252')
There’s thirty days in June
```

My question is how do I convert the unicode string that I'm getting into a plain-text string so that I can decode it?

Comment: `u'\x92'` is a private use character in a Unicode string.  `'\x92'` is a `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` in a cp1252-encoded byte string.  Your API is decoding the string to Unicode incorrectly if you have the former.  It would be `u'\u2019'` if decoded correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems your string was *decoded* with `latin1` (as it is of type `unicode`)

1. To convert it back to the bytes it originally was, you need to **encode** using that encoding (`latin1`)
2. Then to get text back (`unicode`) you must **decode** using the proper codec (`cp1252`)
3. finally, if you want to get to `utf-8` bytes you must **encode** using the `UTF-8` codec.

In code:

```
>>> title = u'There\x92s thirty days in June'
>>> title.encode('latin1')
'There\x92s thirty days in June'
>>> title.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')
u'There\u2019s thirty days in June'
>>> print(title.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252'))
There’s thirty days in June
>>> title.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252').encode('UTF-8')
'There\xe2\x80\x99s thirty days in June'
>>> print(title.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252').encode('UTF-8'))
There’s thirty days in June
```

Depending on whether the API takes text (`unicode`) or `bytes`, 3. may not be necessary.

Comment: This is good, able to handle so many encodings, including eg. Chinese GB18030.

Comment: I like your technique. But I need to compare 2 strings that are localized in Cyrillic for Russian. One string is saved in a SQLite database as a filename. The other is that actual string used as a filename on disk. When I go to verify that the file was correctly generated, the strings are **visually identical** but != when I compare them. Obviously due to encoding. Do I need to know the encoding scheme of the strings before I do the encode/decode sequence to produce 2 identically encoded strings that will match?